# Check if all integers in array are the same - C

Tags: arrays, c

I've been given an exercise that asks the user to **decide the size of the array** to a maximum of 30, **fill it**, and then **check that all numbers contained within it are equal**.

I tried this way, but the result is always "The elements of the array are not all the same", even though they are.

Could someone give me a hand? Below I insert the code that I have already written

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_DIM 30

int check(int[], int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int dim;
    int num;
    int flag;
    int arr[MAX_DIM];

    printf("Insert an array dimension. \n");
    printf("Remember that the maximum size the array can take is %d \n\n", MAX_DIM);
    printf("Array dimension: ");
    scanf("%d", &dim);

    if (dim <= MAX_DIM) {
        arr[dim];
    } else {
        printf("Array dimension isn't valid! \n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter the numbers to place in the array of size %d ", dim);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }

    int equals = check(arr, dim);

    if (equals == 1) {
        printf("he elements of the array are all the same \n");
    } else {
        printf("he elements of the array are not all the same \n");
    }  

}

int check(int arr[], int dim) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: As a statement, `arr[dim];` does nothing useful. It might lead to *undefined behavior* if `dim` is out of bounds, but nothing else.

Comment: You also never initialize the elements of your array, it will be left in an uninitialized state where all elements will have an *indeterminate* value (think of these values as garbage).

Comment: And if `dim == MAX_DIM` then in the `check` function the last iteration of the loop will lead to `arr[i + 1]` being out of bounds. For this I recommend you loop from `1` instead, and check `arr[i] != a[i - 1]` instead.

Comment: Aside, you don't even need a check function, you can do the check in the `scanf` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main issues (and other minor issues):

1. The scanf statement is populating variable num but not the array, which is never initialised.
2. The loop in the check function should stop at the second last index. Going to the end means you are comparing with an out of bounds value at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_DIM 30

int check(int[], int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int dim;
    int num;
    int flag;
    int arr[MAX_DIM];

    printf("Insert an array dimension. \n");
    printf("Remember that the maximum size the array can take is %d \n\n", MAX_DIM);
    printf("Array dimension: ");
    scanf("%d", &dim);

    if (dim >= MAX_DIM) {
        printf("Array dimension isn't valid! \n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter the numbers to place in the array of size %d ", dim);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        scanf("%d", arr + i);
    }

    int equals = check(arr, dim);

    if (equals == 1) {
        printf("The elements of the array are all the same \n");
    } else {
        printf("The elements of the array are not all the same \n");
    }  

}

int check(int arr[], int dim) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < dim - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: It may not be necessary to include it in the code (for clarity), but it should at least be mentioned that the return value of `scanf` must be checked.  If the input stream begins with `X`, every `scanf` will fail to perform any conversions and undefined behavior abounds.

Comment: First answer addressing the errors in the OP code, so +1 from me. As a next step I will recommend the OP to consider data types. E.g. `stdbool.h` is included so why not make the return value of `check()` a `bool`. And could `dim` and array indices be `unsigned` integers (possibly after a few adjustments to the code)?

Comment: I'd rather write `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);` which IMO is easier to understand, even if `&arr[i]` is semantically equivalent to `arr + i`

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the vale from scanf. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        arr[i]=num;
    }
```

Comment: This should rather be a comment, because it does not address all problems.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Agree, but I don´t have enough reputation to add a comment

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the actual array values replace your scanf call with `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);`

Comment: This should rather be a comment, because it does not address all problems.